# Two way mapping class for static strings in php

Tags: php

What could be the best way to implement 2 way mapping class for static strings in php. I thought having Enum class having 6 constants for 2 way mapping of 3 key value pair. Please suggest better implementation.

Eg:if I have a following mapping, I need to get Mangalore if I refer M and I also need to get M if I refer Mangalore

> M=> Mangalore
>       D=> Delhi
>       O=> Ooty

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought having Enum class having 6 constants for 2 way mapping of 3 key value pair. Please suggest better implementation.

Don't need a special class for this unless you absolutely need to. Simple PHP Arrays can do this

```
<?php

$names=array();
$names["M"]="Mangalore";
$names["D"]="Delhi";
$names["O"]="Ooty";

echo $names["M"]; //  Mangalore
echo array_search("Mangalore", $names); //M
?>
```

**Edit**

You could also write a small function for this

```
<?php

$names=array();
$names["M"]="Mangalore";
$names["D"]="Delhi";
$names["O"]="Ooty";

echo getMapping($names,"M");
echo getMapping($names,"Mangalore");

function getMapping($values,$search)
{
    if(array_key_exists($search,$values))
    {
        return $values[$search];
    }
    $key=array_search($search,$values);
    if($key)
    {
        return $key;
    }
    return 0;
}


?>
```

Comment: As I need it to be static, I used your implementation in a class as Static array and static functions... I guess this is right .. thanks a lot !!